# How do I check the value of a Vim option in Vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, options

In Vimscript, how can I check the current value of a Vim option?

To elaborate, I want to make a command to switch from Full-GUI Mode ( `guioptions=+tM`) to Hacker Mode (`guioptions=-tM`).

However, I can't seem to find a way to parse the `:set guioptions?` value

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `&{option-name}` in an if-statement like so:

```
if &guioptions ==# "Trl"
    echo "Toolbars and scrollbars are present!"
elseif &guioptions ==# ""
    echo "No toolbars and scrollbars present!"
endif
```

The `&` specifies that the variable name is a Vim option.

See [`:help :let-&`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-%26) for the full documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Akshay solved it:
Just posting the resulting function case other people might need / want it.

```
function! ToggleMenuBar()
    let l:menu_option = strridx(&guioptions, "m")
    let l:toolbar_option = strridx(&guioptions, "T")
    if l:menu_option > 0
        set guioptions-=m
    else
        set guioptions+=m
    endif
    if l:toolbar_option > 0
        set guioptions-=T
    else
        set guioptions+=T
    endif
endfunction
```